# Is there any problem in my elasticsearch request?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to update a doc in elasticsearch by using:

```
POST /rcqmkg_eco_ugc_rec/_doc/aaa/_update
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.flower_cnt_0 += params.flower_cnt_0",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
      "flower_cnt_0": 1
    }
  }
}
```

But I got a `illegal_argument_exception` error. The result of elasticsearch is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "remote_transport_exception",
        "reason": "[data1_xxx][xxx][indices:data/write/update[s]]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "failed to execute script",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "script_exception",
      "reason": "runtime error",
      "script_stack": [
        "ctx._source.flower_cnt_0 += params.flower_cnt_0",
        "                                  ^---- HERE"
      ],
      "script": "ctx._source.flower_cnt_0 += params.flower_cnt_0",
      "lang": "painless",
      "caused_by": {
        "type": "null_pointer_exception",
        "reason": null
      }
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Where is the problem in my update request of es?

Comment: Does the document that you want to update contain a non-null field named `flower_cnt_0`? If yes, which value does it have?

Comment: `flower_cnt_0` may be not exist in this document

Answer (score 1):

If the document you're trying to update might not contain a field called `flower_cnt_0`, you need to account for this in your script:

Try this instead:

```
POST /rcqmkg_eco_ugc_rec/_doc/aaa/_update
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.flower_cnt_0 = (ctx._source.flower_cnt_0 ?: 0) + params.flower_cnt_0",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
      "flower_cnt_0": 1
    }
  }
}
```